# How can I drop strings contained in other string contained in the same string list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings and need to remove items contained in other items like shown:

```
a = ["one", "one single", "one single trick", "trick", "trick must", "trick must get", "one single trick must", "must get", "must get the job done"]
```

I just need to drop every string contained in another string in the same list, like: "one" is contained in "one single" so it must be dropped, then "one single" is contained in "one single trick" so also need to be dropped

I have tried:

```
b=a
for item in a:
    for element in b:
        if item in element:
            b.remove(element)
```

expected result:

```
a = ["trick must get", "one single trick must", "must get the job done"]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you defining what is the control strings in this case. That is the string that you are checking against? Is it the longest ones?

Comment: @Edeki Okoh thanks for your interest, Not especifically, I just need to drop every string contained in another string in the same list, like: "one" is contained in "one single" so it must be dropped, then "one single" is contained in "one single trick" so also need to be dropped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension should do this quite nicely, combined with Python's [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
a = [phrase for phrase in a if not any([phrase2 != phrase and phrase in phrase2 for phrase2 in a])]
```

result:

```
>>> a = ["one", "one single", "one single trick", "trick", "trick must", "trick must get", "one single trick must", "must get", "must get the job done"]
>>> a = [phrase for phrase in a if not any([phrase2 != phrase and phrase in phrase2 for phrase2 in a])]
>>> a
['trick must get', 'one single trick must', 'must get the job done']
```

Comment: Note that solution this costs *O(n^2)* in time complexity.

Comment: that's true @blhsing - I didn't imagine you could do it any better than O(n^2). I'm looking at your solution at the moment to see how it's done! :)

Answer (score 2):

An efficient approach to solve the problem in *O(n)* time complexity is to use a set that keeps track of all the sub-phrases given a phrase, iterate from the longest string to the shortest, and only add the string to the output if the it is not already in the set of sub-phrases:

```
seen = set()
output = []
for s in sorted(a, key=len, reverse=True):
    words = tuple(s.split())
    if words not in seen:
        output.append(s)
    seen.update({words[i: i + n] for i in range(len(words)) for n in range(len(words) - i + 1)})
```

`output` becomes:

```
['one single trick must', 'must get the job done', 'trick must get']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @blhsing!

Answer (score 1):

Not an efficient solution, but by sorting longest to smallest and removing the last element we can check if each appears as a sub string anywhere.

```
a = ['one', 'one single', 'one single trick', 'trick', 'trick must', 'trick must get', 
     'one single trick must', 'must get', 'must get the job done']
a = sorted(a, key=len, reverse=True)
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    x = a.pop()
    if x not in "\t".join(a):
        b.append(x)

# ['trick must get', 'must get the job done', 'one single trick must']
```